# Where can I find Spree.t method definition or documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am new to rails and Spree. I am investigation a rails project that uses Spree. I came across to this

```
Spree.t(:num_orders)
```

But couldn't find what it actually does.
Little help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about I18n. See this [guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/customization/i18n.html)

Comment: If anyone has found if/where this is defined in the spree codebase, I would also like to know. Even if it's just an alias definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first tools that you reach for in the toolbox are not very helpful. For instance, using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) in the Spree repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/spree/spree.git
cd spree

rg "def t\b"
# no results ...
```

You could try searching for **alias** and **alias_method**; however, it's annoying narrowing down the search results because the method only has a single character.

It's better to reach for more advanced debugging techniques. Please see **Aaron Patterson**'s guide: [I am a puts debuggerer](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html)

Example from the rails console:

```bash
[2] pry(main)> Spree.method(:t).source_location
=> ["/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spree_core-4.1.8/lib/spree/i18n.rb", 12]
```

Opening this file and looking around **line 12**:
[image]

So, **Spree.t** is alias for **Spree.translate** which inherits from **ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper**

You can find the documentation and source here:

- [Rails API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate)
- [Rails source at GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L70)

So, Spree is just adding some enhancements to Rails's built-in translate method which also has an alias of "**t**" if you look at the API docs.